# if_else_loop program error the else statement does not display its content ( java code )

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to display the 99 bottle beer song as per my code i am not getting the else statement, the program should have while and if statement, else statement though may or may not be included

```
public class bottles {

public static void main(String... s){

int beer = 99;

while(beer>=1){

if(beer>1){

System.out.print(beer + "bottles of beer on the wall ");
System.out.println(beer + "bottles of beer ");
System.out.print("Take one down and pass it around ");

beer = beer-1;

System.out.println(beer + "bottles of beer on the wall ");  

}   

if(beer==1){

System.out.print(beer + "bottles of beer on the wall ");
System.out.println(beer + "bottles of beer ");
System.out.print("Take one down and pass it around ");
System.out.println("no more bottles of beer on the wall. ");
System.out.println("");
}

else{

System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.");
System.out.println("Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on thewall");
}



}

}

}
```

output is not taking the else statement. novice in java

Comment: You're not using `else if` which causes the `else` block to be executed 98 times.

Comment: Your code is without any indentations making it all left justified and almost impossible to read, understand and debug. Please re-format your posted code by giving it proper indentations, usually 4 spaces per block, and making sure that all code on the same block is on the same indentation level. Your cooperation in this would be greatly appreciated and will likely improve your chances of getting a decent and prompt answer.

Comment: actually it should take else in every single iteration...

Answer (score 0):

because your loop only get run `while(beer>=1)`

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop will execute until you have no more beer. 
This means the last time it gets executed is with 1 beer left.
Your `else` statement can never be executed.

So just put `System.out.println("No more...` under your `while` statement ( without the `else` ):

```
while( more than 0 beer) {
    do sth...
}

// No more beers left
print "no more beers left";
```

Answer (score 0):

else is not reach, because there is no way that `beer` can become zero.
You should add `beer = beer-1;` into the the `if(beer==1)` block.

Edit: Oh and yes your while loop exits if beer becomes zero. Change your while condition to `while (beer >= 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Your else will never run ,As if beer>1 your first if works,if beer==1 ,it does beer-- ,so value of beer==0 ,and you are out of your loop.Beer value is ranging from 99 to 0.

Conditions:

1: value>1 and <99 : First if value takes it and keeps decreasing

2: value reaches : 1 , 2nd if handles it for you , does beer-- ==0;

3: value==0 , beer(0)>=1 is false so you are out of loop, while not executed . SO your else was never reached by code

```
 while(beer>=1)  //will run only if beer>=1
 {

if(beer>1)
{  //execute if beer>1

     beer -- //  this will work till beer>1

}   

if(beer==1)
{ //if beer==1 , this will execute

       beer-- // val of beer==0 ,So next time loop does't work

}

else{    // will be never called, if beer==0 you will never reach inside while so this never executes

}

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the code try this one

```
 public static void main(String... args)
{
    int beer = 10;

    while(beer>=1){

    if(beer>1){

    System.out.print(beer + "bottles of beer on the wall ");
    System.out.println(beer + "bottles of beer ");
    System.out.print("Take one down and pass it around ");

    beer = beer-1;

    System.out.println(beer + "bottles of beer on the wall ");  

    }   

    if(beer==1){

    System.out.print(beer + "bottles of beer on the wall ");
    System.out.println(beer + "bottles of beer ");
    System.out.print("Take one down and pass it around ");
    System.out.println("no more bottles of beer on the wall. ");
    System.out.println("");
    }

    else{

    System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.");
    System.out.println("Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on thewall");
    }
    beer--;
    }
}
```